# Laravel join with conditions on 2 tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my application the users can create a task and assign it to a project that ca be either active or archived, or it can be created without a related project.

What I'm trying to do now is to fetch all the tasks created by company users that are either assigned to active projects or that have no project assigned.

I managed to complete the first part with the following code inside the `Company` model:

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Project', 'company')
        ->join('tasks', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('projects.id', '=', 'tasks.project')
                ->where('projects.status', '=', Project::STATUS_ACTIVE);
        });
}
```

This function fetches all the company tasks assigned to active projects, but I also want to fetch the tasks that are not assigned to any project (this is indicated by the `project` column in the `tasks` table set to 0).

The problem is that I don't know where to put the `orWhere` condition. I tried many changes but none of them worked.

Furthermore, there's one thing I don't get: why is the join function not something like the following?

```
$this->hasMany('App\Task', 'company')
    ->join('projects', ...
```

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: @JonathanCrowe Version 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for some time I eventually found a solution to my problem.

My main issue was due to a misunderstanding of the Eloquent ORM and/or the Database Builder.

What I did to solve the issue is the following:

```
$companyTasksQuery = DB::table('tasks')
    ->where('company', '=', $this->id)
    ->where('project', '=', 0)
    ->where('status', '=', Task::STATUS_INCOMPLETE);

return $this->hasMany('App\Task', 'company')
    ->join('projects', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('projects.id', '=', 'tasks.project')
            ->where('projects.status', '=', Project::STATUS_ACTIVE);
    })
    ->select('tasks.*')
    ->union($companyTasksQuery);
```

As you can see from the code above I kind of switched the join. Previously I was joining the `projects` table with the `tasks` but now I'm doing it the other way around and the `->select()` fixed my issue (as you can see from my previous code I missed completely the `select`.

In order to add the other condition I simply added it as an union with another query that is selecting all the incompleted tasks that are not assigned to any project.

Comment: It seems you're trying too hard.. You could simply use `hasManyThrough` relation for this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood really well your issue. If you could post your models and how the relationships are defined it would help a lot.
Anyway for navigating through queries I use the following "rule":

[image: Schema]

And then for retrieving the registers from table1 that are related to any register from table5 and filtered by a certain id value for table5.

```
public function navigation($table5ID){  
    return Table1::whereHas('table2',function($query) use ($table5ID){
        $query->whereHas('table3',function($query2) use ($table5ID){
              $query2->whereHas('table4',function($query3) use ($table5ID){
                $query3->whereHas('table5',function($query4) use ($table5ID){
                    $query4->where('table5_id',$table5ID);
                });
            });
        });
    })->get();
}
```

I made [a post on my personal blog some time ago](http://namelivia.com/eloquent-query-through-many-tables/). Hope this helps.

Comment: You can do it with single `whereHas` call and dot nested relations.